# Getting unique column names to allow a creation of a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm currently trying to create a view from two tables by doing a join, I've methods used here but i'm still getting this error:

> Msg 4506, Level 16, State >1, Procedure vw_Employee, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 19]
>   Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'empNumber' in view or function 'vw_Employee' is specified more than once.

My view is as follows:

```
create view vw_Employee as
(
    select * 
    from Employees e1 
    inner join EmpInfo e2 on e2.empNumber = e1.empNumber
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because both the tables have `empNumber` column and you are using `*` to select. There shouldnt be any ambiguity/collisions in column names in the select. Assuming the only common column name is empNumber.

```
create view vw_Employee as
(
select * from Employees e1 inner join EmpInfo e2 
using (empNumber)
)
```

I'd recommend you to explicitly list all the column names you need.

```
create view vw_Employee as
(
select e1.empNumber, . . .
from Employees e1 inner join EmpInfo e2 
on e2.empNumber = e1.empNumber
)
```

#### EDIT:

Based on your comment, try:

```
create view vw_Employee
as
(
        select e1.empNumber,
            e1.firstName,
            e1.lastName,
            e1.ssn,
            e1.job,
            e1.projectId,
            e2.[address],
            e2.[state],
            e2.zip,
        from Employees e1
        inner join EmpInfo e2 on e2.empNumber = e1.empNumber
        )
```

Comment: `create view vw_Employee as
(
select e1.empNumber, e1.firstName, e1.lastName, e1.ssn, e1.job, e1.projectId, 
e2.[address], e2.[state], e2.zip, e2.empNumber from Employees e1 inner join EmpInfo e2 
on e2.empNumber = e1.empNumber
)`

Comment: @Danny - Now see the **EDIT** in my answer.

Comment: Perfect, works as intended. So when joining two tables to create a view I don't have to declare the column from the second table since I already selected it from the first table.

Comment: @Danny - Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

you must write the name of column in select query and take only e1.empNumber